# How to get the value of the selected result on pressing enter in extjs combobox

Tags: extjs

I have a combobox and i navigate through the search results using the UP/DOWN arrow keys and when i press enter on a particular result,i load a different view and i also need the value(against the valuefield)of the selected result.

I have used specialkey event and  `if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER)` then i do a getValue() and then i load the view. But on getValue(), i get the raw value ie the string that i displayed and not the value against the valuefield(i have displayField:'Name' and valueField:'id').

I also tried firing a select event and in its listener i do a combo.getValue(), still i get the raw value and not the value against the valuefield. I need the id because i may have 2 or more search results with the same name but each one will have a unique id.

Is there a way i can get the value ?

Comment: can you adjust this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jandalf/TtKWm/) so that I see your problem, cause this example is working

Comment: I use MVC & in my controller I have a listener for specialkey event and select event. I fire  event to load a different view when Enter is hit and I want to set the value (against value field) of the selected result  from the combobox in a variable before the view is loaded. But the problem is View is loaded before and then  the value is set.  
specialkey :function(field,e){
if(e.getKey == e.ENTER){
// var value = field.getValue();  //this gives me the raw value and not the actual value
fireEvent(‘loadView’);
}
},
select :function(combo){
var value =combo.getValue();//get actual value here
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dT3ZL/. Similar to this fiddle,but i need the value before the the view loads.As of now the view loads and then i get the value

Comment: Just wanted to know ,is select  the only event which can give me the actual value (specified against the valuefield) or are there more events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the combobox hooks into 2 events of the picker which should be interesting for you:

```
me.mon(picker, {
    itemclick: me.onItemClick,
});

me.mon(picker.getSelectionModel(), {
    selectionchange: me.onListSelectionChange,
});
```

source: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox

you need to hook into this events and then you should have your value

Comment: thanks....I checked for these events in the extjs 4.2.1 docs,but I could not  find itemclick or selectionchange in Ext.form.field.Combobox or in Ext.for.field.Picker.If possible,can you post a sample example...

Comment: sorry i can only point you in the right direction, have no time to dive deeper into it, but here are the events: [selectionchange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-selectionchange) and [itemclick](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-itemclick)

Comment: Also I want to set the highlighted value in the search results in the combobox textfield when UP or DOWN arrow keys are pressed.Tried using highlightAt function,but this is not working in IE8.Is there any other way of doing this?It would be a great help....thanks